# Error Messages should Match Labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a form. Many of the labels need to have a different name than they are given in the model.

```
attr_accessible :pin
```

Simpleform view:

```
= f.input :pin, :label => "Secret Code"
```

When validation fails, the error uses the model's name for the field ("Pin"), rather than the label I set in the view ("Secret Code"). The user will be confused on what field has the error.

Currently I have a helper that changes the label:

```
def fix_pin_errors(msg)
  msg.gsub!('Pin', 'Secret Code')
end
```

If I am doing this for many fields, however, it becomes tedious and not DRY.

What is the best way to have errors match labels that differ from the names the model gives them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I18n is your friend.  Read [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).  It will explain how to globally convert these so they get picked up everywhere you need.

For your example, it might look something like this:

In `en.yml`:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      your_model_name:
        pin: 'Secret Code'
```

Comment: I figured it out and added the specifics for posterity.